# Is the set $(0,1)$ limit point compact?

Tags: general-topology

We call a set limit point compact if every infinite subset has a limit point. It seems like the set $(0,1)$ (in the subspace topology of the Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}$) would be limit point compact because *every* point is a limit point, and hence any infinite subset will also have some limit point.

However, as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, compactness and limit point compactness are the same. And I know that $(0,1)$ is not compact. So what am I missing here?

Comment: Consider the set $\{1/n : n \geq 2\}$ in $(0, 1)$. Its only limit point is $0$, which is not in $(0, 1)$

Comment: Try the infinite set $\{1/n : n =2,3,4,\dots\}$.

Comment: I think that by "every infinite subset having a limit point" they mean that every infinite subset has a point in the superset (in this case $(0,1)$) to which points of the infinite subset can be found arbitrarily near.

Comment: @Vercingetorix  Ah I see. I was thinking that $U$ being limit point compact meant any infinite subset $A \subset U$ must have a limit point of $U,$ but it means instead that it must have a limit point of $A$ itself.